# Environment variables not work for IntelliJ IDEA HTTP client

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA, I want to define environment variables for HTTP client, [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html) is the document, but IDEA cannot find my environment when I run a request.

what's wrong？

[environment config picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODNT4.png)

[request config picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WmrE.png)

IDEA version:

IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)

Build #IU-201.7223.91, built on April 30, 2020

Comment: Make sure you don't have the env.json files located in the .idea folder: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-239351

Comment: Thanks,  I solved it by move `http-client.env.json` from Scratches to project root folder.

Comment: Try removing spaces after semicolons in the envir variable list. I had manually edited it and left spaces in. Removing them mysteriously worked.

Answer (score 2):

right click on http-client.env.json and "Override File Type" select **JSON**.
This helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have the env.json files located in the .idea folder: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-239351

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in a project with multiple modules.

The solution is to move your yourfile.rest / yourfile.http and your http-client.env.json to any of below locations

1. to yourmodule/src/test/
2. to IDEA Intelj scratches folder (c:\Users<youruser>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Intelli...\config\scratches\

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by invalidating the IntelliJ caches.
In IntelliJ, go to File > Invalidate Caches, select all available options, and then click on "Invalidate and Restart".